# node-imap, mail event not working when multiple email comes

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap, node-imap

I am using node-imap library to read mail, mail event is not getting triggered 2nd time after initialization.

below is my code

also, its giving Error: read ECONNRESET as error after 1st retrival of the email.

Expecting imap.once('mail', function (x) { } should invoke whenever any new mail arises in the mailbox.

imap.once('mail', function (x) { } is not getting triggered triggered.

This event triggers only once when I run the node.js file, and later it is not getting triggered. Please sugggest.

```
imap.connect();

imap.once('ready', function () {
    console.log("Imap ready");
    readMail();
});

function readMail() {
    openInbox(function (err, box) {

        imap.once('mail', function (x) {
            console.log("New Mail...", x);
            executeMail(err);
        });
    });
    }
}
```

Tried below as per the comment but, still doses not worked.

```
function readMail() {
    openInbox(function (err, box) {

        imap.once('mail', function (x) {
            console.log("New Mail...", x);
            executeMail(err);
            imap.connect();
        });
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: When the connection is closed, that's what ECONNRESET means, you need to run `imap.connect()` again. If you don't, that connection is closed and remains closed for the rest of eternity.

Comment: Where should I mention imap.connect() ? currently, imap.connect() executes only once when file gets initialize while node application starts!!! 
I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: ECONNRESET means that the connection was reset. Nothing more will happen after that point. Whether, when and how to reconnect is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should use `imap.on` not `imap.once`

```
imap.on("mail", mail => {
  console.log("New mail arrived 1");
});
```

The above code worked for me.